# How can I raise the power of the first number(user input) to the second(user input)?

Tags: java, for-loop, multiplication

```
  import java.util.*;

  public class Group2_p2 {

  static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args)

  {
    int num1 = 0, num2, answer = 0;

    System.out.println("Please enter first number");

    num1 = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter second number");


    for (num2=console.nextInt() ; num2>0; num2--) {

      answer = num1 * num2;

    }
    System.out.print(answer);

  }

  }
```

Please enter first number
 [5]
Please enter second number
 [2]
5>

My issue is that I'm not receiving the correct answer. I have to take two numbers and the first number is to be raised to the power of the second number. 
Most likely a really silly mistake but I'm having a brain fart on this. I'm still a beginner.

Comment: You could use: `Math.pow()`

Comment: Not allowed to use Math.pow()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = 0, num2, answer = 1;
        System.out.println("Please enter first number");
        num1 = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter second number");
        for (num2=console.nextInt(); num2 > 0; num2--) {
            answer = answer * num1;
        }
        System.out.print(answer);
    }
```

You should keep multiplying your answer by num1 every iteration and updating answer.  Also you should change answer to be 1 to start with.

Comment: Thank you, much obliged. I see my mistake now. I shouldn't have multiply by num2 since it's iterating as well.

Comment: @ParmanandPhaskanram your welcome! But know that it is not just because it is iterating...power is the base times itself n number of times which is your `num2` so `5^3` would be `5 * 5 * 5` or `num1 * num1 * num1` in your case you store in answer so `answer = answer * num1;` 3 times.